# Laravel - How to validate based on condition using Rules Request

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 application, by default company_id in the table is 0:

I have this Request Rules validation:

```
    'email' => [
        'required',
        'email',
        'min:5',
        'max:80',
        Rule::unique('users', 'email')
    ],
     'company_id' => [
        'nullable',
    ],
```

I want email to be unique based on two conditions:

1. If no company_id is selected, the email should be unique.
2. If company_id is selected, the email should be unique with company_id.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you show full validation rules.is company_id passed in request

Comment: Try conditional rules as per Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: @JohnLobo - I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom rule

```
'email' => ['required',
    'email',
    'min:5',
    'max:80',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail)use($request) {
            $company=Company::where('email',$value)->where(function ($query)use($request){
                if(!empty($request->company_id)){
                    $query->where('company_id',$request->company_id);
                }
                
            })->exists();
            
            if($company){
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        
        },
    ],
```